# navbar position fixed on scroll causes next element an sudden scrolltop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a fixed navbar on scroll.
I only want to apply the `position: fixed;` on the navbar and not the entire header, because I don't want to include the announcement bar to be fixed on scroll when it is visible.

But every time I scroll up to specified scroll height, there is a sudden shift caused by adding class of `fixed-navbar`. I want a smooth scroll without the said behavior.

See this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hG8So1BASO5H37PJmMnB9uI2eY0HWgKa/view?usp=sharing) for reference.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GreenArrrow/weq0s31h/11/)

I tried adding margin-top or padding top to next element to header but same behavior happens. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Here are my codes**
**HTML**

```
<!-- ===== Header ====== -->
    <header class="header">
      <!-- Announcement Bar -->
      <div class="announcement-bar show">
        <div class="container">
          <p class="announcement">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore,
            saepe.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="nav-brand">
            <a href="index.php">
              <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Tea Creations Co. Inc. logo" class="nav-logo"/>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-list-container">
            <button class="btn close-menu">
              <ion-icon name="close-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <ul class="nav-list">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="products.php">Products</a></li>
              <li><a href="franchise.php">Franchise</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li class="nav-login">
                <a href="account.php" class="btn-account">
                  <ion-icon name="person-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon> Account
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-icons">
            <button class="btn btn-search">
              <ion-icon name="search-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <a href="account.php" class="btn btn-account">
              <ion-icon name="person-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon>
            </a>
            <a href="cart.php" class="btn btn-cart">
              <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon>
              <span class="cart-counter">2</span>
            </a>
            <button class="btn toggle-menu">
              <ion-icon name="menu" class="icon"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- ===== Header End ====== -->
    
    <!-- ===== Banner End ====== -->
    <section class="banner">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 class="banner-heading">
              Serving the Richest <br />
              Milktea in the City
            </h1>
            <p class="banner-text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure
              eum excepturi pariatur, commodi laboriosam accusamus!.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- ===== Banner End ====== -->
```

**CSS**

```
/* ----- Header ----- */
/* Announcement Bar */
.announcement-bar {
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: var(--clr-primary);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.announcement-bar.show {
  display: block;
}
/* Navbar */
.navbar {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition: padding 300ms;
}
.navbar.fixed-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    navbar.classList.add("fixed-navbar");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("fixed-navbar");
  }
});

const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".toggle-menu");
const closeMenu = document.querySelector(".close-menu");
const navListContainer = document.querySelector(".nav-list-container");

toggleMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navListContainer.classList.toggle("show");
});
closeMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navListContainer.classList.remove("show");
});
```

Comment: use `position: sticky` instead of `fixed`. `position: fixed` moves an element out of flow and as such every element will take its place straight away by default. Also note to include code directly in the question as [repro]. Using fiddels as standalone is not allowed (you even where warned while posting).

Comment: I have tried `position: sticky;` but it isn't working. It won't stick to the top as I scroll. My guess is because I am only applying the `fixed-header` to the `navbar` which is child of `header` element. When I apply `position: sticky;` to the header, it works. But just like I said in my problem, I don't want the entire header to be fixed on scroll. Only the navbar, excluding the announcement bar if it is visible.

Comment: When you adding `fixed-header` to `navbar` then you need to calculate height of `navbar` and add style on body like: **body{padding-top: `calculated navbar height`+px}**.

Answer (score 0):

U have two option

1. if u use ur format position absolute wont occupie space beacause of that u will face this issue for that u add one more tag wrap around navbar set min height for that so wont face this issue
   example:

   ```
    .set-min-height{
      set-min-height:100px;
      //remeber this height should be same as navbar height

     }

    <div class="set-min-height">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-brand">
                    <a href="index.php">
                        <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Tea Creations Co. Inc. logo" class="nav-logo" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-list-container">
                    <button class="btn close-menu">
                        <ion-icon name="close-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="nav-list">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="products.php">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="franchise.php">Franchise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-login">
                            <a href="account.php" class="btn-account">
                                <ion-icon name="person-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon> Account
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-icons">
                    <button class="btn btn-search">
                        <ion-icon name="search-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon>
                    </button>
                    <a href="account.php" class="btn btn-account">
                        <ion-icon name="person-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon>
                    </a>
                    <a href="cart.php" class="btn btn-cart">
                        <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="icon"></ion-icon>
                        <span class="cart-counter">2</span>
                    </a>
                    <button class="btn toggle-menu">
                        <ion-icon name="menu" class="icon"></ion-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
   ```
2. u have to use position sticky for the navbar and make sure there is no parent element should not set to overflow hidden property